# A java interpreter written in java

Tags: java, syntax, tree, interpreter, javacc

I'd like to write a Java interpreter, in Java, with the intention of adding some other features to the language.

I was wondering if there was already some Java interpreters existing, written in Java, using javacc.
That would be cool.

I have already downloaded the java 1.5 grammar and Abstract Syntax Tree(AST) on the javacc website, but the problem is that the AST is just built, but not filled. In fact it does nothing.

Do you know any opensource Java interpreter written with javacc ?

Thank you,

Loic

Comment: You don't write interpreters with JavaCC. You write compilers. It appears that what you really want to do is write a compiler. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You can write an interpreter with it. There is an example in the .zip I downloaded where it is used to write an interpreter.
I also have a TinyBasic interpreter written with javacc.

Comment: @EJP You generate parsers with it; what they're used for is arbitrary.

Comment: the canonical response to 'I'd like to have ...' is "I'd like to have a pony.' Seriously, though, questions like this are closed as nonconstructive.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have indeed encountered interpreters that contained parsers. They were not competently written in other ways as well. There is no requirement for parsing in a Java interpreter, and no evidence here that interpreting is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @EJP My point was that you don't write compilers with javacc, you generate parsers, which can be used for anything, including compilers and interpreters. I don't understand the point you're trying to make--I agree the question needs clarification, I disagree regarding what javacc is (as does javacc itself).

Comment: I'd check out the old [polyglot project](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/polyglot/) although IIRC it tops out at Java 1.5. Some interesting work utilized it, my own and others. You may find it adequate, however, and has some nice features. The old [Java Syntactic Extension](http://jse.sourceforge.net/) (?) is even older, and worked in a different way, but might also be a useful starting point. Both were great fun for me.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not arguing with you about what JavaCC does. The point is simply that introducing JavaCC into the question is *prima facie* evidence, although not conclusive, that he is talking about a compiler rather than an interpreter: as his desire to extend the *language.* It is all evidence of 'not a real question'.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, guess I misunderstood what "you don't write interpreters with javacc meant"--my bad. While the question may have suffered from a language barrier issue, I honestly don't see what's wrong with the notion of a Java interpreter with language extension, but perhaps that's because I've spent a lot of time doing things just like that.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier There is nothing either useless or unconstructive about a request to clarify your question, with reasons. You didn't do so, and your question was subsequently closed. I suggest it was your *reaction* that was both useless and unconstructive.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you know any opensource Java interpreter written with javacc ?

The short answer is No, I don't.

I spent a few minutes Googling and couldn't find anything relevant.  However, there are examples of interpretters for other languages written in Java using JavaCC.  I also saw a reference to a Compiler Construction course which has (had) writing an interpreter for a "microJava" language as a homework exercise.

But think about it.  Why would someone go to the effort of writing a compiler / interpretter for Java in Java?  Its a lot of work to build something that the existing tool chains do already.  And even more effort to then make it available for others to use. That probably explains why you can't find one.

I suggest that you do your experiments starting from the OpenJDK codebase ... or by implementing a compiler that generates bytecodes or Java source code.

---

The Polyglot system that Dave Newton mentioned (in a comment above) is a framework for doing Java language extension that ultimately generates regular Java source code.  It is interesting, but I don't see how it would help here.